# Yii2 Undefined index

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

My controller:

```
    $params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;

    $query4 = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['monthsubmit', 'modeler'])
    ->from('sku3d')
    ->groupBy(['monthsubmit', 'modeler'])
    ->orderBy(['monthsubmit'=>SORT_DESC]);

    $query4->andFilterWhere(['like', 'monthsubmit', $params['monthsubmit']])
           ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'modeler', $params['modeler']]);

    $dataProvider4 = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query4,
    ]);
```

MY view:

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider4,
    'filterModel' => true,  
    'pjax'=>true,
    'panel' => [
        'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
        'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>Submitted SKU by Month</h3>',
    ],
    'columns' => [
        // 'monthsubmit',
        [
        'attribute'=>'monthsubmit', 
        'filter' => Html::input('string', 'monthsubmit')
        'width'=>'310px',
        'group'=>true,  // enable grouping
    ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'modeler', 
        'width'=>'180px',
        'filter' => Html::input('string', 'modeler')
        'group'=>true,  // enable grouping
        ],  
    ]
]); 
?>
```

I have created sqlDataProvider in my controller and its working. My problem is when i try to create a filter option since im not using the search model for my gridview, it return error `Undefined index: monthsubmit`.

Please tell me where I'm wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: have you added it to the search rules in your model?

Comment: It means there is no query params named `monthsubmit` in the request.

Comment: @paul thanks, so how can I fix it? I don't really understand how queryParams work

Comment: @SaoHo Since comment isn't suitable place for multi-line code, I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you should do as this

```
$modeler = Yii::$app->request->get('modeler');
$monthsubmit = Yii::$app->request->get('monthsubmit');

$query4 = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['monthsubmit', 'modeler'])
    ->from('sku3d')
    ->groupBy(['monthsubmit', 'modeler'])
    ->orderBy(['monthsubmit'=>SORT_DESC]);

$query4->andFilterWhere(['like', 'monthsubmit', $monthsubmit])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'modeler', $modeler]);

$dataProvider4 = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query4,
]);
```